# Basic Inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I have that $|L_j|<(\Delta t) A_1+ hA_2$

I need it in the form $|L_j|<(\Delta t+h)A_L$
where $A_L=A_L(A_1,A_2)$ and $A_1, A_2,A_L$ are all constants.

I have thought maybe combing the facts that if

$A_1<A_2$ then $A_L=A_2$ and if

$A_1>A_2$ then $A_L=A_1$

Any thoughts on how I would do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following works if $A_1,A_2 \ge 0$. Similar things can be done otherwise.

Define a function $\max:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ by
$$\max (a,b) = \cases {a~~~\text{ if } a>b\\
b~~~\text{ if } a\le b
}$$

Set $A_L = \max(A_1,A_2)$.

Then $|L_j| < (\Delta t)A_1+ hA_2 \le (\Delta t)A_L + hA_L=(\Delta t + h)A_L$. This is basically what you did, but also contains the case $A_1 = A_2$. The function $\max$ is sometimes represented by $\max(a,b) = a\vee b$.